# Arrow function ES6

Tags: javascript, feathersjs

I have a basic understanding of arrow [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). I however came across this piece of code and am some what stumbled.

```
const errors = require('@feathersjs/errors');

const test = () => async context => {
   //omited
}


module.exports = {
  before: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [test()],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  },  
 };
```

What exactly is this line doing ?

```
const test = () => async context =>
```

It looks like some form of double arrow functions?

I am including the hooks code as it is part of the library feathersjs and this function is writing a [hook](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html) before a particular call.

Comment: It's a function that returns a function, yes :D

Comment: `test` is a function that returns another async function that takes a `context` argument

Comment: [currying-in-javascript-arrow-function](https://medium.com/@harouny/currying-in-javascript-arrow-function-sequence-2a510441215a)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not passing curly braces, then the arrow function by default returns the value you're pointing it to. So think of it this way,

```
let testValue = () => 'some value';
```

is the same as

```
let testValue = () => {
   return 'some value';
};
```

So your function can be written as

```
let test = () => {
   return async context => {
       // some process
   }
};
```

Basically the function is returning another function, this is called **Currying** and is a way of creating higher order functions and helps avoid repeatedly passing some values. For example, if I have a helper function which helps me create a multiplier

```
let multiplier = (x) => (y) => x * y;
let multiplyBy5 = multiplier(5);

console.log(multiplyBy5(5)); // 25
```

I basically created a function multiplyBy5 which creates a function to multiply my values by 5, and I can create more multipliers for different values.

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to a function returning a function. In olden javascript this would go something like:

```
function test() {
   return async function() {
       //do something(probably await op)
   }
}
```

Comment: you forgot about the `context` that OP have